# jwplayer showing video, but no sound on iphone

Tags: ios, jwplayer

JWplayer is showing video, but playing no sound on iphone only.

I'm using version 7.4.3

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("video-player").setup({
        flashplayer: "./jwplayer-7.4.3/jwplayer.flash.swf",
        file: './media/help_where_is_my_course.mp4',
        width: '100%',
        height: '300px',
        controlbar: 'bottom',
        autostart: true,
        preload: true,
        mute: false,
        aspectratio: '4:3'
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MP4 container format with the H.264 video codec and the AAC audio codec is natively supported by desktop/mobile Internet Explorer, Safari and Chrome, but Chromium and Opera do not support the format. IE and Chrome also support the MP3 audio codec in the MP4 container, but Safari does not. Firefox/Firefox for Android/Firefox OS supports the format in some cases, but only when a third-party decoder is available, and the device hardware can handle the profile used to encode the MP4.

Source https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Answer (score 0):

There may be an issue with the file itself, or the toggle switch on the left side of the phone is set to vibrate/silent. Do you have a direct link to a sample mp4?

Comment: I'm using browserstack to check. It's definitely not on silent. I have access to this mp4 since it is being hosted locally.  I'll try with another mp4 to see if that's the issue.

Comment: It's unfortunately not the video. I tried another and I'm having the same results.

Comment: If you access the mp4 directly in the browser without the player, is there sound? Does that behavior happen here? http://demo.jwplayer.com/stream-tester/er

Comment: your url got cut off there. The video does show up in the browser with no sound. Does this mean iphone isn't liking my mp4s?

Comment: Yeah, you should make sure it's encoded using the H.264 video codec and the AAC audio codec.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I used BrowserStack, but I don't know if it transmits sound or not. Try going to YouTube or something like that and see if you get sound there.